# Emitting signal when project property is changed using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

QGIS API provides `QgsExpressionContextUtils` to set project properties.

But in the class, there isn't any signal.

I hope to connect to a signal whenever some of the properties were changed.

So is there a way to implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It's the `customVariablesChanged` signal from `QgsProject`.

```
def my_slot():
    print("A project variable was just changed!")

QgsProject.instance().customVariablesChanged.connect(my_slot)
```